# Dynamically append/prepend content from one div to another - with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 3 column div with multiple rows. What is the most dynamic way to extract content from the first div and append/prepend this to the 3rd div - Ensuring that all following divs follow along.

here is my example code:

```html
 <div class="content">
   <div class="item">
    <div class="col1">
     <div class="img1">
      <img src="img_in_first_col">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3">
     <div class="img2">
      <img src="img_in_third_col">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="col1">
     <div class="img1">
      <img src="img_in_first_col">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3">
     <div class="img2">
      <img src="img_in_third_col">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item">
    <div class="col1">
     <div class="img1">
      <img src="img_in_first_col">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col2"></div>
    <div class="col3">
     <div class="img2">
      <img src="img_in_third_col">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I've tried using something along the lines of:

```html
$('.item .col1 .img1').each(function(){
 $(this).prependTo('.item .col3 .img2')
})
```

but what i get is all the images being added to all the rows.
Please help! thanks in advance

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you give some feed-back?

Comment: Thanks all - I tried all submissions but they didn't give me what I needed. But they did give a point in the right direction. I took a different logical approach in the end

Comment: Please describe your approach in an answer (you are allowed to answer your own questions), so that the question is fully documented. This might be useful for future visitors searching the site with similar enquiries.

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as this:

```
$(".col1").each(function (index, element) {
  $(this).closest(".col3").prepend($(this).contents());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to insert column 1 after column 3:

```
$('.col1').each(function(){
  $(this).insertAfter($(this).siblings('.col3'));
});
```

... or before column 3:

```
$('.col1').each(function(){
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings('.col3'));
});
```

Used jQuery functions:

- [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)
- [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)
- [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)